# How to catch function call

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, c++14

*NOTE: this topic is not about debugging and try,throw,catch, i can't place anything in my functions directly, only external influence like with WINapi.*

I need a some way to get info in my APP if ANY function is called. It should "catch" function call in runtime, i can't implement any extra code for  each function is exist in my APP. Some WINAPI i suppose should work, but i can't find proper which would handle every call from process. As info would be nice to have 3 things:

1. entryPoint(address) of function which just get called.
2. would be nice to define what return type this function have.
3. it's parameters like (int, char) for example.

P.S. would be great to know how much functions are currently executing in my(or maybe other) process.

Comment: There are folks here who know stuff about Win32 I've never dreamed of, but I don't think you're  not going to get much satisfaction. Outside of what's on the stack, C++ doesn't track this kind of stuff at runtime. Heck, after compiling the function call might not even exist. You can reverse engineer some of the information discarded when the code blender that is an optimizing compiler is done with debugger information files or a memory map, but not easily and not with any tool I know of at runtime (excluding a debugger) .

Comment: There's nothing that actually does exactly what you ask, but [Detours](https://github.com/microsoft/detours) is probably the closest you'll find. Or look up how instrumentation is done. Either way, you'll enter a world of pain, limitations and platform specific things.

Comment: @MikeVine tnx for such answer. But can't find an installation download for desktop of this app. First in google is Detours from microsoft, but can't even go that page. Access denied(strange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something when functions from your application are called, you have to compile with `/Gh` command line switch [Enable _penter Hook Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h.aspx) and maybe also `/GH` [Enable _pexit Hook Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc11y76y.aspx). Then you can define `_penter` function (and maybe also `_pexit`) which would be called when entering (leaving) your application functions.

These switches have to be entered manually in project properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line.

Functions have to be `naked`:

```
extern "C" void __declspec(naked) _cdecl _penter( void ) {
    // Save registers.
    _asm {
        push eax
        push ebx
        push ecx
        push edx
        push ebp
        push edi
        push esi
    }  

    // Your code here.

    // Restore registers.
    _asm {
        pop esi
        pop edi
        pop ebp
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop ebx
        pop eax
        ret
    }
}
```

Be prepared for noticeable slowdown.

You can experience very nasty reentrancy problems and stack overflows, when you call your functions from `_penter` or `_pleave`. Use some protecting variable or call only naked functions.

Next step would be to extract data from `PDB` file, but it would help if you could describe what you want to do with this information. Are you planning to re-implement profiling or function coverange tests?

We can't use the `__func__` macro because we are in the wrong function to do so. Maybe generating detailed map file would be enough. We could get the return address and lookup it in the map file.

Additional links:

- [Debug Interface Access SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/debug-interface-access-sdk?view=vs-2017)
- [microsoft-pdb](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb/)
- [How to Inspect the Content of a Program Database
  (PDB) File](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37456/How-To-Inspect-the-Content-of-a-Program-Database-P)

Comment: That is a good answer. As i see nothing will be easy with such request of my. Want to see what other people might advice in next two days. If nothing better will appear - this answer will be the best.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

Functions do not exist at runtime, not in general.  They don't have names.  Their types are just bits.  Under as-if the call itself can be eliminated.

There are many things somewhat close to what you describe.  Profiling, instrumentation, using DLLs as proxies, among others.  I mean with debug symbol tables (pdbs from MSVC say) you could interrupt a process 10 times per second and profile it.  But none match your requirements, so the answer remains no.

Comment: To help clarify an otherwise confusing sentence, _"as-if"_ refers to a rule for C++ compilers which says they can make any code transformations so long as the resulting code behaves _as if_ it were the original. This includes replacing function calls with their inlined bodies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have private pdb symbol file for your executable, you can write a simple debugger that loads your executable and lets you inspect the executable. You can set software breakpoints on the functions that you are interested in and it will break into your debugger. Based on which breakpoint it hit, you can then use Microsoft Debug Interface Access SDK (DIA SDK) to get information about that function parameters, return value, etc. Look for MinDBG, a simple Win32 debugger on how to write a simplest of a debugger. Also look up DIA SDK Api's on how to decipher the exe. This will only work if you have private symbols for your executable.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the exact context, but maybe you can write an other C++ file:

- Override the function
- Log the parameters, timestamp,...
- Call the overridden function

Something like that:

```
void A::foo(a,b,c)
{
  // log timestamp, parameters...
  B::foo(a,b,c);
  // log elapsed time, returned value...
}
```

Comment: I don't have problem with such things. I have problem with finding that function(s) in memory address and it's basic parameters like return type and amount of arguments(an thier types if it's possible)